# iPhone - Putting and manipulating an Image from the Camera in a UIImageView

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

This is what I want to do:

1. Take the camera image an put it in a small (not full screen) UIImageView.
2. Manipulate the image in realtime (e.g. give half of it a red tint).

I have checked around this subject and uncertain as to the best approach. People are recommending both UIImagePickerController and AVCamCaptureManager, or is there something else.

Could I have your advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

  CGContextSetFillColor(context, CGColorGetComponents([UIColor colorWithRed:0.5 green:0.5 blue:0 alpha:1].CGColor)); // don't make color too saturated

  CGContextFillRect(context, rect); // draw base

  [[UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage.png"] drawInRect: rect blendMode:kCGBlendModeOverlay alpha:1.0]; // draw image
  }

In the rect variable pass the area of the image you would like to tint

Comment: Sorry, I clearly didn't explain myself properly. I can do that. What I want to achieve is to pass 1) the video feed from the iPhone's camera to the Rect and then in phase 2) work out how to intercept the image and doctor it. It's how to get the video image that is perplexing me.

Comment: in phase one you record the video and store it and then in phase two you want to extract images is that correct?

Comment: Let's put it another way. I have the video feed (real time) coming into a UIImageView on the screen and I want to tint part of it. Doing this with a picture is straightforward as per your example. What I don't understand how to do this with the video feed as there is no obvious png, or equivalent, to work on. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok this is what you can do if you just want to show a tint on the live stream add another image view having a transparent image with the tint over the image view capturing your video hope that helps :)

Comment: Yes that's it, create a subview with the rect (tinted) and then release and redraw as it's required. I was presuming it's possible to manipulate the video image directly but that doesn't seem possible. Many thanks.